# WebRTC: Implement peer to peer chat over LAN

Tags: node.js, html5-video, chat, webrtc

I want to implement webrtc video peer to peer chat over lan network. The MDN states that a mediator server is necessary for the application to communicate because of multi user chat. But, If only a 2 people chat is to be implemented, then is there a way to do so without mediator server in Nodejs. The application to be made, will function over LAN.

Comment: they would still need some sort of signaling server to find each other

Comment: Cant those peers signal each other?

Comment: how would one peer know the existence of other?

Comment: What I did to implement a tcp server chat is, I sent a UDP signal from the application, and all the application will respond to that UDP signal by a tcp signal. Which would thus make the machine know all other machine on the network.

Comment: i misread the `node.js` part, i thought this chat was going to be based on browser

Comment: if this is not over browser, not sure of the need for webrtc, can't it be done over sockets( not that i know how to implement that)

Comment: Actually its a `node-webkit` application. If you could just tell me how to implement a video chat over lan using nodejs, in node-webkit application, then it would be really helpful.

Comment: You can use socket.io in nodejs to act as the signalling server with webrtc. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spromano/WebRTC_Book). Also you want to implement a simple text chat or a video chat?

Comment: I have implemented a simple text chat using the basic tcp module present in nodejs. But for now extending my application to support video chat, I am trying to find a way, thus came across WebRTC.